# Access data outside of Closure // iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift

How do I access "user" outside of the closure?

```
    let currentUser = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child((FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser?.uid)!)
        currentUser.observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let name = value?["name"] as? String
        let age = value?["age"] as? String
        let user = UserStruct.init(name: name, age: age)
    })
```

Everything is right in Firebase and the data is there and is not nil. But I need to reference "user" outside of the closure like so:

```
print(user.name)
print(user.age)
```

Comment: You need to either define user outside the scope of the closure, and populate it in the closure, then wait on the closure to finish before using user, or you could use a completion handler

Comment: What do I declare user as outside of the scope since it's taking in a Struct? A dictionary? I tried using completion handler but I don't where I'm supposed to place it.

Comment: well `User` is a `UserStruct`, so declare it as that.

Comment: Ok so I tried this, var user = [UserStruct](), and changed this to this, self.user = [UserStruct.init(name: name, age: age)], and reference it like this, print(user[0].name). But I got fatal error index out of range

Comment: From my first comment: "then wait on the closure to finish before using user"

Answer (score -1):

Declare the `user` variable outside of your closure and then access it using the `self` modifier.

```
    var user: UserStruct
    let currentUser = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "users").child((FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser?.uid)!)
        currentUser.observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { snapshot in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let name = value?["name"] as? String
        let age = value?["age"] as? String
        self.user = UserStruct.init(name: name, age: age)
    })
```

Comment: I get this error, Class 'ViewController' has no initializers

Comment: it ran by doing this, var user: UserStruct!, but I'm getting an optional value still in viewDidLoad

Comment: Please post the code you're referring to and which line the error occurs.

Comment: If you're getting Class 'ViewController' has no initializers error, you're probably declaring your variable as non-optional and not assigning a value in init method, then swift complains that you have a variable which is supposed to have a value, but does not have one. In that case declare your variable as optional and later access it using optional binding.